# Combing 2 sass mixins @transition and @vendor without errors

Tags: css, sass

I have 2 sass mixins that I would like to combine, 1 being for transitons and the other to handle vendor prefixes, so basically I want to transition the translateY value of an element so want to do something like the following:

```
@include transition( @include vendor(transform, .3s ease-in-out) );
```

**Mixins**

```
@mixin vendor($property, $value...){
    -webkit-#{$property}:$value;
    -moz-#{$property}:$value;
    -ms-#{$property}:$value;
    -o-#{$property}:$value;
    #{$property}:$value;
}

@mixin transition($args...) {
    -webkit-transition: $args;
    -moz-transition: $args;
    -ms-transition: $args;
    transition: $args;
}
```

If anyone could advise how I actually do this or if there is a much better way that would be great. I don't need to use compass in case anyone suggests that.

Comment: Have a look at Compass and its transition mixins: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/transition/#mixin-transition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### With Compass

Compass is definitely the way to go about vendor prefixes. Then all you need to do is something like:

```
@import "compass";

test {
  @include transition( transform 0.3s ease-in-out );
}
```

and the output will look like:

```
test {
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: -o-transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9208295)

---

### Own vendor mixins and functions (no Compass)

If for some reason you wouldn't use compass you can try making your vendor mixin a bit more exciting and add some functions (to check if an argument needs to be prefixed). Maybe something along these lines:

```
// loops through all arguments and prefixes the ones that need it (in this case only transform)
@function vendor-args($arg, $vendor) {
    $result: ();
    @each $i in $arg {
      @if $i == transform { $result: append($result, #{$vendor}$i); }
      @else { $result: append($result, $i); }
    }
  @return $result;
}

// general vendor mixin 
@mixin vendor($property, $args...){
  @each $vendor in ('-webkit-', '-moz-', '-ms-', '-o-', '') {
    $out: null;
    @each $arg in nth($args,1) {
      $out: ($out, vendor-args($arg, $vendor));
    }
    #{$vendor}#{$property}: $out;
  }
}

// general transition mixin
@mixin transition($args...) {
  @include vendor(transition, $args);
}

// test
test {
  @include transition( transform .3s ease-in-out, color .2s linear );
}
```

#### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9208634)

Or if you want to check against a list of properties that need prefixing and not just `transform`, you can add another tiny function:

```
@function needs-vendor($p){
  $l: transform, another-property-you-want-prefixed, and-another;
  @each $i in $l {
    @if $i == $p { @return terue; }
  }
  @return false;
}
```

and then use `needs-vendor($i)` instead of `$i == transform`.

Another thing is ... you don't really need to prefix transitions with `-ms-`. So you could make the vendor mixin take a list of prefixes as an optional argument, and use it like so:

```
@mixin transition($args...) {
  @include vendor(transition, $args, ('-webkit-', '-moz-', '-o-', ''));
}
```

and **voilá**, here you go:

### [DEMO](http://sassmeister.com/gist/9208748)

But if you go with Compass it will do all the hard thinking for you ;-)